# Reading JSON into JavaScript using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

I have an external JSON file that I am trying to read into my ajax and parse through, but I'm missing something. I'm trying to read it into an `XMLHttpRequest` object. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong. I get no results.

```
External file (mypeeps.json) contains:

[
{"name":"Frank","age":"23","image_url":"frank.gif"},
{"name":"Jim","age":"24","image_url":"frank.gif"},
{"name":"Tom","age":"21","image_url":"frank.gif"},
{"name":"Betty","age":"28","image_url":"frank.gif"},
]
```

My code is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ajax_get_json() {

            var p = new XMLHttpRequest();
            p.open("GET", "mypeeps.json", true);
            p.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            p.onreadystatechange = function () {
                alert("Im in...");
                if (p.readyState == 4 && p.status == 200) {
                    alert("Let me know I've gotten this far");
                    var data = JSON.parse(p.responseText);
                    var results = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;
                    results.innerHTML = data.name;
                } else {

                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "waiting...";
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "processing...";
        }
    </script>

    <div id="myDiv"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        ajax_get_json();
    </script>
```

Comment: this line is problematic `results.innerHTML = data.name;` because you are getting an array not an object with a single attribute

Comment: can you check the console to see if you are getting the object at all? try adding `console.log(data);` after the data var is set.

Comment: Hi gabereal, Thanks for the quick respons. You are right. The log shows ReferenceError: data is not defined. Anny suggestion on what to change?

Comment: I'm thinking I should do something like:

var data[]; and do a for(item in results){ data.push.item }?

Comment: firstly, you need to call `p.send();` in your ajax_get_json function to make the request.